# Twitter style time in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rubygems

I am looking for a gem which is capable of converting the given time into
a format like "1 Minute ago", "Just now", "5 days ago"etc.,

I have once came through a gem like this, but cannot able to find it again.

Could anyone give me a hand on this?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Rails' includes built-in [DateHelper](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/DateHelper.html) methods [time_ago_in_words](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/DateHelper.html#method-i-time_ago_in_words), [distance_of_time_in_words](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/DateHelper.html#method-i-distance_of_time_in_words), and [distance_of_time_in_words_to_now](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/DateHelper.html#method-i-distance_of_time_in_words_to_now) that provide this manner of formatting.

Comment: Or the slightly more generic [distance_of_time_in_words](http://apidock.com/rails/ActionView/Helpers/DateHelper/distance_of_time_in_words)

Comment: Thanks, @Gareth. Added both `distance_of_time_in_words` and the convenience method `distance_of_time_in_words_to_now` to my answer.